# Random Choice loop through groups of samples

Tags: pandas, loops

I have a df containing column of "Income_group", "Rate", and "Probability", respectively. I need randomly select rate for each income group. How can I write a Loop function and print out the result for each income bin.

The pandas data frame table looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df={'Income_Groups':['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3'],
   'Rate':[1.23,1.25,1.56, 2.11,2.32, 2.36,3.12,3.45,3.55],
   'Probability':[0.25, 0.50, 0.25,0.50,0.25,0.25,0.10,0.70,0.20]}  

df2=pd.DataFrame(data=df)

df2
```

[Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUHaG.png)

Comment: please also add the expected dataframe

Comment: @anky_91:Thank you so much for your help. Your code worked.

Comment: i must be dreaming, i didnot post an answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Shooting in the dark here, but you can use `np.random.choice`:

```
(df2.groupby('Income_Groups')
    .apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x['Rate'], p=x['Probability']))
)
```

Output (can vary due to randomness):

```
Income_Groups
1    1.25
2    2.36
3    3.45
dtype: float64
```

You can also pass `size` into `np.random.choice`:

```
(df2.groupby('Income_Groups')
    .apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x['Rate'], size=3, p=x['Probability']))
)
```

Output:

```
Income_Groups
1    [1.23, 1.25, 1.25]
2    [2.36, 2.11, 2.11]
3    [3.12, 3.12, 3.45]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy.apply` because of the weights.

```
import numpy as np

(df2.groupby('Income_Groups')
    .apply(lambda gp: np.random.choice(a=gp.Rate, p=gp.Probability, size=1)[0]))

#Income_Groups
#1    1.23
#2    2.11
#3    3.45
#dtype: float64
```

---

Another silly way because your weights seem to be have precision to 2 decimal places:

```
s = df2.set_index(['Income_Groups', 'Probability']).Rate

(s.repeat(s.index.get_level_values('Probability')*100)  # Weight
  .sample(frac=1)                                       # Shuffle |
  .reset_index()                                        #    +    | -> Random Select
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['Income_Groups'])            # Select  | 
  .drop(columns='Probability'))

#  Income_Groups  Rate
#0             2  2.32
#1             1  1.25
#3             3  3.45
```